# On click event only fires once, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been having this problem for the past week but I just skipped it for this time.

So this is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $('.mPicture').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).find('div').bPopup();
        });
    });
});
```

I have seen that people needed to use .live for getting it to work multiple times but that doesn't do anything with this code.
This code is connected to a div which isn't visible until an image is clicked.
So what my question is: Why doesn't this work and what do I need to change?

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="product_tabs_new_contents" class="product-tabs-content" style="display: none;">
   <div class="Merk">
      <table id="tbLogo">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div id="AS" class="mPicture">
                   <img src="logo's/AS.png" id="mPicId" class="mPicMaat"/>
                  <div class="logoPopup" style="width: 700px; border: solid; border-color: white; border-width: 5px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: white; padding: 25px; font-size: 25px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;">
                      <img src="logo's/AS.png" class="merkThumbnail" />
                     Put your text here
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

If any other information is needed, feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you also add the HTML?

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` may be blocking the other events, try removing and trying once.

Comment: I've tried this: `$('.mPicture').on('click', function () {
            $(this).find('div').bPopup();
        });
` and it didn't work unfortunately...

Comment: Please give us working fiddle

Comment: you should bind 'click' event on parent `div`, because as you said that the `div` isn't visible ultil an image is clicked: You cannot bind an eventListenner on any element if it's not exist. in this case, the code is look like `$('#tbLogo').on('click', '#test', callbackFunction)` , or `$('#tbLogo').on('click', '.mPicture', callbackFunction)` . You should learn more about DOM.

Comment: @jh kaiz: this is the answer - so move it from a comment to the solution ;) to Sj03rs - check this out: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: i think the onclick is firing properly but the code inside the onclick may be causing the issue. Also i DON'T think this is because of event delegation, you can always assign events to elements which are not visible. event delegation is needed only when a new element is CREATED.

Comment: what did `$(this).find('div').bPopup();` do? And did you get any error in the `console` after the `onClick` fires for the first time?

Comment: @errand Thanks for reference the document, I'll include it in the answer also :).

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found the issue

```
$(this).find('div').bPopup();
```

is changing the html structure while rendering and its not reverting back to its original position.

**From:**

```
<div id="product_tabs_new_contents" class="product-tabs-content" style="display: none;">
   <div class="Merk">
      <table id="tbLogo">
         <tr>
            <td>
               <div id="AS" class="mPicture">
                   <img src="logo's/AS.png" id="mPicId" class="mPicMaat" />
                  <div class="logoPopup" style="width: 700px; border: solid; border-color: white; border-width: 5px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: white; padding: 25px; font-size: 25px; box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;">
                      <img src="logo's/AS.png" class="merkThumbnail" />
                     Put your text here
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

**to:**

```
<div id="product_tabs_new_contents" class="product-tabs-content" style="display: block;">
   <div class="Merk">
      <table id="tbLogo">
         <tbody><tr>
            <td>
               <div id="AS" class="mPicture">
                   <img src="logo's/AS.png" id="mPicId" class="mPicMaat">
                   // Removed from here 
               </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
   </div>
</div>

// and added here
<div class="logoPopup" style="width: 700px; border: 5px solid white; border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; background-color: white; padding: 25px; font-size: 25px; box-shadow: gray 0px 0px 10px; left: -115.5px; position: absolute; top: 127px; z-index: 9999; opacity: 0; display: none;">
    <img src="logo's/AS.png" class="merkThumbnail">
                     Put your text here
</div>
```

Comment: Did you mean the jQuery code does this, or do we need to change it to this.

Answer (score 0):

you should bind 'click' event on parent `div`, because as you said that the `div` isn't visible until an image is clicked: You cannot bind an eventListenner on any `element` if it was not exist. in this case, the code is look like:

```
$('#tbLogo').on('click', '#test', callbackFunction)
```

or

```
$('#tbLogo').on('click', '.mPicture', callbackFunction)
```

reference document by @errand :
http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/